# TFS release mangement of console applications

Tags: tfs, build, app-config, release

I have a console application where I need some ideas on how to build/release the config part of the application. When running locally in VS the config file is called app.config. After a build the file changes to .exe.config. We are using XDT transformation for building the config file to the different enviroment. But what would be the smartest way to ensure the naming convension is correct when release the build version to a server?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to use TFS Build and deploy to multiple environments via Release Management.

For handling configuration in Release Management, there are two techniques generally used **Config Per Environment** and **Tokenization**.

If you prefer a clean separation between build and deploy. To achieve that, recommend **tokenizing** configuration.

More details please take a look at this wonderful blog: [Config Per Environment vs Tokenization in Release Management](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/config-per-environment-vs-tokenization-in-release-management)

Environment specific application settings values configured in the app.config are tokenized. Above blog's method essentially inserts tokens into setting values during the build process. When deployed the tokens are replaced with matching Release definition configuration values.

Besides, for an example of a separate build and release solution, you could also take a look at this blog: [Using web.config transforms and Release Manager – TFS 2017/Team Services edition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alming/2017/02/09/using-web-config-transforms-and-release-manager-tfs-2017team-services-edition/) (similar to app.config)